# Why does TypeScript complaint about missing property in generic inheritance?

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following test case :

```
interface BaseFoo {}

interface FooAdapter {
  method<F extends BaseFoo>(foo:F):string;
}


interface ConcreteFoo extends BaseFoo {
  value:string;
}

class ConcreteFooAdapter implements FooAdapter {
  method(foo: ConcreteFoo): string {
    return foo.value;
  }
}
```

The only error is with the `method` signature, where TypeScript complaints that :

> Property 'value' is missing in type 'BaseFoo' but required in type 'ConcreteFoo'.

Why would `value` be present in `BaseFoo` since the generic `F` is supposed to extend it?

But, more importantly, how to fix this so there is no error?

#### Edit

Here is an alternative solution I was trying to investigate, but with similar failure:

```
interface BarAdapter {
  method<F>(bar:F):string;
}

type Bar = {
  value:string;
}

class ConcreteBarAdapter implements BarAdapter {
  method(bar:Bar):string {
    return bar.value;
  }
}
```

It complaints that `F` is not assignable to type `Bar`, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I'd say you've misplaced the generic type parameter scope.  You probably mean to have `FooAdapter` be a generic interface instead of having `FooAdapter` have a generic method.  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WK9yDN) shows.  With your version, *callers* choose the type argument `F`.    Does that address your question fully? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your updated edit has the same problem; a `BarAdapter`'s `method` must work for any `F` the *caller* chooses, so a caller should be able to write `barAdapter.method(123)`.  But `ConcreteBarAdapter`'s `method` only accepts `Bar`s, so it's not a valid `BarAdapter`.  Again, I think you want to make `BarAdapter` a generic interface with a specific method, instead of a specific interface with a generic method, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WG4VJw).  Does that work for you or not?  If it works I will write up an answer (probably tomorrow because it's my bedtime now )

Comment: I was hoping to have the generics at the method level, but it does work, yes.

Comment: Can you explain why you wanted the generics there? Is there a use case for that?

Comment: @jcalz Sure! All "adapters" have a given method that is invoked by user code, however their return is the same, the parameters are specific to each adapters. For example, `AuthAdapter` may have an `authenticate` method with `CredientialsAuthAdapter` and `EmailAuthAdapter` extending that interface, but having the method receiving different parameter types.

Comment: Oh well, I see that @GuerricP has posted essentially this answer, so I won't bother with mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only criteria is that the parameter should extend `BaseFoo`, and the return value should be a `string`, you may not need generics at all, this would be enough:

```
interface BaseFoo { }

interface FooAdapter {
  method(foo: BaseFoo): string;
}

interface ConcreteFoo extends BaseFoo {
  value: string;
}

class ConcreteFooAdapter implements FooAdapter {
  method(foo: ConcreteFoo): string {
    return foo.value;
  }
}
```

This provide as strong typing as in your attempt with generics. TypeScript constraints `method` in the implementor to **extend** `method(foo: BaseFoo): string`.

However, if you need to be able to use the adapters as implementors of a specific `method` signature, then you'd have to add the generic parameter on the **interface**, and then provide the type explicitly when implementing it:

```
interface BaseFoo { }

interface FooAdapter<F extends BaseFoo>  {
  method(foo: F): string;
}


interface ConcreteFoo extends BaseFoo {
  value: string;
}

class ConcreteFooAdapter implements FooAdapter<ConcreteFoo> {
  method(foo: ConcreteFoo): string {
    return foo.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, even if generics are fancy and really useful, sometimes the simple solution is best. Thanks!